# HPC: Multiple independent serial jobs submission between nodes

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, gnu-parallel

I have 4 directories(name:1,2,3,4). Each one has an executable file of C code with name submit. Using `#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=2`, gave me 4 workers(2 on node-1 and 2 on node-2).

Task: I need to run each 4 files on 4 different folders independently.

```
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=2
./1/submit&
./2/submit&
./3/submit&
./4/submit&
```

Above forking method only chooses node-1 and forks all 4 jobs between 2 workers of node-1 and never goes to node-2.

```
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=2

mpirun -np 1 -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE ./1/submit&
mpirun -np 1 -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE ./2/submit&
mpirun -np 1 -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE ./3/submit&
mpirun -np 1 -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE ./4/submit&
```

I tried using mpirun, but it still forks only between node-1 workers.
Kindly suggest if there is any method to divide jobs between nodes.

**Update's on the question after Ole Tange's answer**

(1) Directory structure and it's contents are as follows:

ParentDirectory has PBS file "sub.sh" and sub-directories 1,2,3,4. Each sub directory has submit file which is an executable file compiled with icc compiler.
submit file is a molecular dynamics executable code which generates files into the folder from where job is submitted.

(2) Running jobs on 1 node , 4 cores ==> 4 threads in total;

sub.sh has the contents,

```
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=4
cd 1;./submit&
cd ../2;./submit&
cd ../3;./submit&
cd ../4;./submit&
```

sub.sh is submitted from the parent directory then it goes inside individual directories and creates threads for each folder. And hence the resulting files are generated inside each 1,2,3,4 directory without any interference from the other directories or threads. [The resulting video looks like this which is correct](https://youtu.be/5DTrIQ0jWzw)

(3) Running jobs using gnu-parallel on 2 node , 2 cores==> 4 threads in total:

sub.sh has the contents,

```
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=2
seq 4 | parallel --wd . -S 2/"$node1" -S 2/"$node2" ./exx
```

exx has the contents

```
cd 1;./submit&
cd ../2;./submit&
cd ../3;./submit&
cd ../4;./submit&
```

sub.sh is submitted from the parent directory. After I submitted sub.sh, I have seen that jobs are running on each folders 1,2,3,4 and generating files inside the directories, and the speed is comparable to serial code, which means that at least all 4 workers are working. But when I make the video of the results of 1 folder it looks strange, as you can see that the blue swimmer oscillates a lot, which I might be because of the race around condition , [video](https://youtu.be/O_QprJORpjI)

Surely something strange is going on in between the threads. I don't know.

Comment: Have you consulted your HPC-infrastructure HelpDesk & HPC-Support Team  ( with what results ) after having re-read the published HPC-infrastructure best practices documentation ( with what results ) first? This is a common standard on HPC-infrastructures, isn't it?

Comment: This is embarrassingly parallelism that is best ran with job arrays instead of a single job.

Comment: @user3666197 Yes I asked the concerned person of HPC. But instead of answering, he said parallelize the code using MPI or Openmp then submit. The issue is, in my place HPC is divided into 2 groups, as low queue and high queue people and I fall in the low queue category, so my code when I take 1node:10cores , takes significant time to start, but 5node:2cores starts quickly. Henceforth I want to submit this way. Job arrays can't solve the problem either.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Job arrays submits separate jobs, we can run only 10 jobs at a time. Like for ensemble average one needs to submit 100's of the codes. Which will take lots of days if I submit the codes separately or with job arrays.

Comment: Then you can use MPI MPMD if your apps are not MPI programs `mpirun -np 1 ./1/submit : -np 1 ./2/submit : ...`. IIRC, pbs provides a `pbsdsh` command that can/should be used instead of `mpirun`. Keep in mind that `mpirun` will return when the slowest task finishes, and you will waste resources if there is some imbalance (that’s why I suggested job arrays in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
seq 4 | parallel --wd . -S 2/node1 -S 2/node2 ./{}/submit
```

Comment: I have no idea if seq 4 | parallel, has any sense to do in between Nodes. I tried but it didn't worked and the error files reads as, "parallel: command not found"

Comment: @yasir You tagged your question with [gnu-parallel]. The error sounds as if GNU Parallel is not installed. If it is not, you can probably use `parallel --embed` on your development machine.

Comment: I have heard it somewhere that this kind of parallelism is possible through GNU Parallel. As you have confirmed it, I will put the effort in installing and understanding the GNU Parallel. Thanks

Comment: @yasir To get started with GNU Parallel start with chapter 1+2: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 and https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf

Comment: I did "seq 4 | parallel --wd . -S 2/$node1 -S 2/$node2 ./file" with contents of file as "./1/submit&  ./2/submit& ./3/submit& ./4/submit&". This way I got all my codes running and producing results in each respective directories(1,2,3,4). But in the results I have seen someoverlap of the data's. Specifically I generate positions in molecular dynamics and It looks from the video that sort of 2 workers of node1 have race around for folders 1&2 and similarly 2 workers on the other 2 folders. Kindly check if your command has anything missing, like -k or --tmuxpane etc.

Comment: @yasir The command is complete. I am surprised if you it to work by using the input you mention. You need to update your question on how the overlapping is visible. It seems there is information you are not including in the question.